# Webpage has too many redirect during passport js logout

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I implement passport js in mean stack with following ways and I get this webpage has too many redirect when logout button is click. Not sure what is wrong with it.
    exports.signin = function (req, res, next) {

```
  passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
    if (err || !user) {
      res.status(400).send(info);
    } else {
      // Remove sensitive data before login
      user.password = undefined;

      req.login(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(400).send(err);
        } else {
          res.json(user);
        }
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
};


module.exports = function (app, db) {
  // Serialize sessions
  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });

  // Deserialize sessions
  passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    request(options, function (err, response, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
}

exports.signout = function (req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you return a 400, do you load an error page? I've seen redirect loops where the user fails to authenticate and then the error page tries to authenticate again.

In this case you are logging out. Is this user permitted to see the next page after logout when they are logged out?

Take a look at your dev tools and post the sequence of requests. Could shed some light on what the redirect loop actually is.